# combine between IN and Like in a request Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I'm looking for how I can combine between "IN" and "LIKE" in a request like this one

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Location LIKE IN (SELECT name FROM CITIES)
```

(I want to retrieve users who have a city mentioned in the table "cities" )

i get an error in my SQL syntax

(i'm using Mysql).

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Cities c ON u.Location like concat('%',c.Name,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on MySQL syntax but try

```
SELECT * FROM Users
INNER JOIN Cities ON Users.Location = Cities.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using LIKE in the first place? Then again, why are you using IN(SUBQUERY) when it's clearly solvable by a simple join:

```
SELECT u.*, c.Name
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Cities c ON u.Location = c.Name
```

Note: This retrieves only users with a city mentioned in cities. If you want the others as well, use left join.